# Get radio button previous state Click event/Uncheck the radio if previously checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

How can I see if a Radio button was already checked in a `click` event?

Actually what I want to do is that, if the clicked radio was previously checked, and user clicks the same radio again, then un-check it.

But the code below always evaluates the if condition t true :P

```
$('input.radiooption').click(function(g) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log("already checked, now uncheck it");
    } else {
        console.log("Not checked");
    }
});
```

**P.S.**

The thing is,
When I click an unchecked Radio button, **it gets CHECKED**

When I click an already checked button, **it gets CHECKED**

So, I want to know a way to determine the previous state of a radio button inside `click` event.

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/24288jh5/)

Comment: This is the default behavior of `radio`

Comment: @Tushar - Not, Untill you didn't click another radio button it does not change

Comment: And how the `radio` can be `unchecked`?

Comment: Are you sure that need radio button instead checkbox???

Comment: yeah, I need radio. because I have a page where non of readio is selected onLoad, and when a user selects any of a radio button, thats okay, but if he wants to uncheck it, then what?
I dont want checkboxes

Comment: @Umair  your logic is totally wrong change radio to checkbox

Comment: @Umair, You are a little confused here. Radio buttons were meant to be required option. Their alternate were checkbox (can be optional). But if you intentionally don't want to use checkbox then hardly you can manage it. A lot of sources here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Umair See my answer below

Comment: what you are expecting ? do u need checkbox behaviour in radio button ?checkthis link it will help you http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a track of the previous state with temp variable:

```js
var prv;
var markIt = function(e) {
  if (prv === this && this.checked) {
    this.checked = false;
    prv = null; //allow seemless selection for the same radio
  } else {
    prv = this;
  }
};
$(function() {
  $('input.radiooption').on('click', markIt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='group' class='radiooption' />
<input type='radio' name='group' class='radiooption' />
<input type='radio' name='group' class='radiooption' />
<input type='radio' name='group' class='radiooption' />
<input type='radio' name='group' class='radiooption' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var makeRadiosDeselectableByName = function(name){
    $('input[name=' + name + ']').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('previousValue') == 'true'){
            $(this).attr('checked', false)
        } else {
            $('input[name=' + name + ']').attr('previousValue', false);
        }

        $(this).attr('previousValue', $(this).attr('checked'));
    });
};
```

Here is full example: http://jsfiddle.net/EtNXP/1467/